# Algorithm sending email notifications

Tags: php, mysql, email, notifications, cron

I am stuck with algorithm to mail notifications for users. Website is built on PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5 .

I have simple one-to-one messaging system built on the site I am working on, and these messages are stored in a database. The task is to send daily email at 9:00am with notification if user has some unread messages waiting for him.

The way how I accomplished it by now is this:

1. I run the script with cron (every 10 minutes) to collect rows after the last ID of checked message (ID is stored in 'notifications_work_table') from 'messages_table';
2. according to collected data, I count how many unread messages has each user on that database and then I make personalised message for each user, and store that message in 'mailing_queue_table' and setting the time to send this message at tomorrows 9:00am (if its past 9:00am this day), or to todays 9:00am (if it's past midnight this day). On 'notifications_work_table' ID is updated to last checked message id;
3. in parallel I run another script with cron (also every 10 minutes) to check if there are any messages to send, if the now() time is past to time when I need to send the message from 'mailing_queue_table'. In one try I send only 100 email messages.

The problems starts there, when user is online and is reading messages already on the fly. For example, user receives a message on 8:05, script, that collects unreads count (1st point) runs on 8:10, but user then reads this message on 8:12, then stored personalised message (3rd point) has false information laying there, and then I have to run again delete query to unset it from queue.

While writing this problem, I had a thought about that I could check for that if user has been online in some sort of interval, and then check should I send him a notification, or he is so active on site, that there is no necessary to store on queue and then send the mail.

Maybe you have some good literature or tutorial to do these things properly. For example, Facebook is great example of sending notifications, but good material is hard to find. Maybe you have some ideas, that you have went through in your programming life and could share with us.

Thanks,

/Rob

Comment: The reading of a message may lead to start this whole process but only for a single user, so notification and email queue will be updated immediately after the message has been read.

Comment: I had such thought, but problem is again there, that I have last checked message ID, and if other conversation isn't read.